# Mysql query in PHP hanging with 3000+ results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that ran perfectly fine up until 2 days ago. It queries a remote database getting quiz data for a couple thousand students. Normally the result set is around 10000 rows.

2 days ago, the script started hanging and I've tracked it down to this query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT qg.userid, ROUND( qg.grade * 100 / q.grade, 2 ) grade, q.grade as qgrade, q.id quizid, qg.timemodified FROM mdl_quiz_grades qg, mdl_quiz q WHERE q.id = qg.quiz AND q.course = 47 And q.id in (-1,153,158,163,170,176,181,184,199,205,206)  Order By userid, quizid
```

limiting results to 3000 is fine, and it executes immediately, but if limited to 3001 it hangs without finishing.

Also I can execute the query in phpMyAdmin with no problem.

Edit: The results limit has been changing. I was just able to get a return of 3700 results and now can no longer.

Edit2: More testing in phpMyAdmin. When accessing records from the 3000+ range, phpMyAdmin will hang and eventually throw a 500 internal server error.

Edit3: Well. testing is suspended. The Remote Database has just started using SSL for database connections, so my previous user isnt working. I now need to configure my client for SSL. I'm guessing they were making adjustments through the week that was screwing with my script.

Comment: Perhaps your PHP code is not expecting more than 3000 results and does something "funky"

Comment: I've literally cut all code out except this query. Its the only thing running.

Comment: It could be a really odd case of corrupted data in that 3001st record which is just throwing a spanner in the works... would just be typical to be at exactly the 3001st record to put a red herring in making you think it's something to do with the number of rows. Servers are sneaky like that!

Comment: Also ... assuming `q.id` is an auto-incremented integer, is it ever going to be `-1` ? Where is that `-1` in your `IN` coming from ..?

Comment: make sure your order by columns and you join columns are all index's

Comment: I'm not sure why the -1 exists tbh. But you're right it doesn't need to be there as there is certainly no id at -1.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. Are you able to fetch at least 1 record?
2. Try increasing the `max_execution_time` in your php.ini file
3. Change memory limit to 128M if it is low

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the first one but Max execution is set to -1

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT qg.userid, ROUND( qg.grade * 100 / q.grade, 2 ) as grade,
       q.grade as qgrade,
       q.id as quizid, qg.timemodified
FROM mdl_quiz_grades qg JOIN
     mdl_quiz q 
     ON q.id = qg.quiz 
WHERE q.course = 47 And
      q.id in (-1, 153, 158, 163, 170, 176, 181, 184, 199, 205, 206)
Order By qg.userid, quizid;
```

I do not know why your performance is suffering.  However, the above query will run faster with the correct indexes.  The best indexes are:  `mdl_quiz(course, id, grade)` and `mld_quiz_grades(quiz)`.